# glPushName() and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: opengl, graphics

I am trying to implement selecting a node in a terrain (represented by triangle
strips). However I cannot use glPushName() between glBegin/glEnd, so I can only
save the whole strip in a name buffer.
Any other ideas how could I select a specific node/triangle with the mouse?

I know that by creating GL_TRIANGLE objects instead of the triangle strip would
solve my problem, but wouldn't that be much much slower?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenGL's selection mode has been deprecated, you should use a CPU-based ray picking algorithm instead (if you really care about picking performance).

http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm